# Read values from console in a loop in Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell

I want to read values(strings) from console in a loop until a certain value is entered.

What is the code for that?

Comment: [Write Yourself a Scheme](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Write_Yourself_a_Scheme_in_48_Hours) and [parsec wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Parsec) is a good start.

Comment: Don't edit the question to a completely different one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Haskell there are a multitude ways of writing such a loop, and the one you choose will depend on context -- i.e. what larger program is this loop part of?

To get you started with some simple imperative-style loops, both the [Haskell Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell) and the [Haskell Wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/) have some good resources:

- [Haskell Simple Input and Output](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Simple_input_and_output)
- [IO for Imperative Programmers](https://wiki.haskell.org/Haskell_IO_for_Imperative_Programmers)

**Update**

From your comment it appears you want to write a "command processor". Have a look at this SO question and answer:

- [Number guessing game error and keeping count of guesses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37082325/866915)

Alternatively, if your bool expression type has a Show instance how about using the REPL in ghci?

```
ghci> :load your_code
ghci> let e = ...initial bool expression...
ghci> e
...e is displayed...
ghci> let f = e || blah
ghci> f
...f is displayed...
ghci> it && whatever             -- it refers to the last expression
...some output...
ghci> not it
...
```

`it` is a variable maintained by ghci which always refers to the last evaluated expression.

Comment: I am working on a boolean logical expresion and i want to read some comands like "put a conjunction on left side" and after every loop to print the moddyfied expression according to the command.